# API for tokensvalue

Tags: tokens, ethereum-wallet-dapp, external-api

I was wondering if there is any API service for getting info about tokens on an ethereum wallet, I found https://ethplorer.io/, but unfortunately with that service there is no possibility to get values from released tokens.

Comment: check out https://etherscan.io/tokens

Comment: Unfortunately it's not possible to get infos about tokens in a wallet address with their API

Comment: their api (https://etherscan.io/apis#tokens) will give you total supply, which may satisfy your needs. anything more, you will have to call the contract yourself.